# PS1() in Python like in Octave?

Tags: python, function, octave, command-prompt

I am taking an online machine learning course in Octave, and I am looking for Python equivalents to Octave's commands. One such command is PS1(), which is a function for changing the characters of the command prompt in Octave to a passed string.

For example, the default prompt in my Octave command line interface is '> ', but I could change it to '>> ' by entering the following command:

```
PS1('>> ')
```

I've tried using the Google search engine, but I didn't find what I was looking for.

Is there a Python equivalent for the PS1() function in Octave and, if so, what is it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it has them, just set [`sys.ps1`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.ps1) and `sys.ps2` variables:

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.ps1 = '$$$ '
$$$ sys.ps2 = '!!! '
$$$ 
$$$ while 0:
!!!     True
!!! 
$$$
```

`sys.ps1` is a prompt for normal lines, while `sys.ps2` is a prompt for blocks that should be indented (and thus, interpreter allow to pass multiple lines before executing them), as you can see in `while` example.

BTW, `sys` module contain many helpful interpreter internal interfaces.